# Ad Hoc Distribution Devices - per app or per developer?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

Apple says I can register up to 100 devices to distribute an application. Is it 100 per app or 100 per developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is per **development account**.

Apple allows you to register up to 100 device in your development portal as test devices. When distributing Ad Hoc apps, you use an Ad Hoc provisioning profile, which contains, among other things, a list of devices on which it can be installed. This list comes from your list of 100 devices. The devices themselves are not at all tied to a particular app, but rather to the development account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know if there's a way to increase that number? And in the next year, the next 100 devices can be different form the previous 100 or do I have to register them again?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I believe that the Numver is always 100 but I am not clear on what happens if you delete a device in year one and then register for a second year. I haven't seen those devices "clear" butni could be wrong.